# What is the difference between CachedNetworkImage and CachedNetworkImageProvider? Which case should each be used in?

Tags: image, flutter, caching, dart

This is in context of Flutter, the Dart based framework for making mobile apps.
I'm looking for sources that can explain the underlying fundamentals and principles, not just a rule of thumb.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're talking about [`package:cached_network_image`](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image), then `CachedNetworkImage` is a *widget*, and `CachedNetworkImageProvider` is an [`ImageProvider`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/ImageProvider-class.html), which identifies the image resource to show.

The `CachedNetworkImage` widget exists for convenience and creates a `CachedNetworkImageProvider` for you from its construction arguments; you alternatively could use a normal `Image` widget with a `CachedNetworkImageProvider`.